# AVFoundation Recording - Strange Error: Index Out of Bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I have quite possibly the strangest error occurring right now with the video recording being done in my app. Using AVFoundation, I set everything up in my view to initialize the camera. Everything works fine and dandy, EXCEPT when the device is sitting horizontal facing up or down. I should mention that this is on iPad 2/3.

This is the exception, according to the debugger:

```
*** AVCaptureFileOutput: ignoring exception '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0
beyond bounds for empty array' that raised during delegate method
```

Now, this error is occurring as soon as I click record, and ONLY when the device is face up or face down horizontal. If I then rotate the device, I am able to record normally, even in these two orientations. This leads me to believe that the current/default orientation of the device when the view first appears is affecting the recording. I'm just not sure why this error occurs, and it is not my code - I've tried breakpoints for `objectAtIndex:`, which returned nothing, and I set breakpoints for exception throws, which only led me on a long goose chase through assembly code.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this had happened to me before when I was using UIWebView. Having deduced from the phrase `ignoring exception` (which I also had seen), your app doesn't crash, does it? If it doesn't, then it seems this is an internal error in Apple's code and you can do two things only: file a bug report to Apple, then do what the system does -- just ignore it.

Comment: Excellent. Nothing like Apple bugs :P I was able to circumvent the error by doing a check for orientation right before I set the orientation of the recording. The app would not crash, but it would short-circuit the recording, leaving no video clips behind. However by doing a check and using a default orientation, I managed to avoid this error and will file a bug. Thanks!